# cpp: error: 'class boost::optional<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' has no member named 'c_str'

Tags: c++, boost

I am new to c++ and trying to fix an issue in my function -

```
Test::Test(const boost::optional<std::string>& name):
    mName(name)
{
        ...
        Some statements
        ...
}

int Test::setResult()
{
     ...
     i=system(mName.c_str())
     ...
}
```

The error I am getting is

```
error: 'class boost::optional<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' has no member named 'c_str'
     i=system(mName.c_str());
                    ^
```

Please help to fix the my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mName` member is of the `optional` type. If you want the string *behind* that `optional`, you need to dereference it with something like:

```cpp
i = system(mName->c_str());
```

Of course, you probably want to first ensure it *has* a value:

```cpp
if (mName) i = system(mName->c_str());
```